# creating a full-screen web slideshow on win

Tags: windows-10, website, javascript, slideshow

i would like to do this from random images in a folder. the web is full of merchants that advertise this, but theirs are normally from specific named pictures. i've seen instructions on how to do it on linux, but i'm not knowledgeable enough to be able to translate it. to my knowledge, this needs a piece of javascript. extra bonus if the same script also does movies.

Comment: I don't know why are you trying to do it using JS if you are apparently absolute beginner. Just use some application capable of this. For example [XnView](https://www.xnview.com/en/) "Settings" > "View" > "Misc." > "Quick slideshow" > "Direction: Random"

Comment: xnview does not do a website, just a local slideshow.

Comment: So you wan to run it on website? Not locally on Win10 machine? Sorry, I'm afraid this is above your actual skill (based on how is the question written). You need some JS/HTML/server backend knowledge for this.

Comment: yup. for now, i've settled with wowslider. https://wowslider.com/rq/jquery-flickr-slideshow/.